# How to reduce package size of PySide6?

Tags: pyqt, pyside6

I am writing a software with [PySide6](https://pypi.org/project/PySide6/). On my Mac the package has a size of 1.0GiB. Is there a way to easily reduce unnecessary files that I don't need to package.

I manually identified the files below as not necessary for my software. Still I end up with more than 500MB.

```
/Assistant.app
/Designer.app
/Linguist.app
/lupdate
/QtWebEngineCore
/QtWebEngineCore.framework
```

Comment: You're probably using other modules than Qt.

Comment: No, I only count the `PySide6` folder that I installed via `pip3 install PySide6`

Comment: That seems unlikely, the whole Qt library, even including web widgets, shouldn't go beyond 2-300mb. Also, what pip installs is one thing, what is in your binary package is another. How did you build it? Please add more details to the question.

Comment: As mentioned, I installed it via `pip3 install PySide6` on an Intel Mac and then located the `PySide6` directory on macOS. It contains 1GB of files.

Comment: I just tried the same on Windows, and it results in a directory of 400MB.

Comment: That's how you installed PySide, but that's not what I asked. You're talking about a "binary size", which makes me assuming that you're trying to *freeze* (create an executable) of your program, so ***how did you build it***?

Comment: Gotcha, and apologies for the confusion. I am soley talking about the PySide directory. I haven't built anything yet. I would copy the PySide6 directory as-is into my app and include it from there. No packaging/freezing involved

Comment: Ok, now it's more clear. I've not use macOS in a while, but it seems strange that even the *whole* PySide6 package would take that much space. I'm under the impression that the pip for macOS also includes the sources for the whole Qt library, which is quite big, indeed, but also unnecessary. The files (C++ binary libraries and python bindings) required for a base PySide setup shouldn't take more than 100mb, even less if you don't use the WebEngine. Instead of using a crude copy of the whole folder, you should opt for a binary executable, using utilities like pyinstaller or cxFreeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can install from PyPi only the [PySide6-Essentials](https://pypi.org/project/PySide6-Essentials/) package.
2. You can [build from source](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/gettingstarted/linux.html) and include via [Qt installer](https://www.qt.io/download) just what you need.

P.S. if you are struggling with building PySide from source I have a [repo](https://github.com/nrbnlulu/pyside-build--from-source) that might help.