# How to reduce the size of a python exe file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

I made a simple program in python using pyqt5. Then I made an .exe file using auto-py-to-exe. The final size was 28MB. Is there any way to reduce the size of the .exe file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reduce package size of PySide6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72898323/how-to-reduce-package-size-of-pyside6)

Comment: I hope this one can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398580/reduce-exe-file

Comment: 28MB is not that big I think.

Comment: A file size of 28MB already seems quite small, considering that it must contain all the dependencies needed to run the script. Anyway, see: [Reducing size of pyinstaller exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47810133/984421).

Comment: Yes, but it would be nice if it could be reduced